# Adjust how much data I've already used this month

Tags: 7.0-nougat, mobile-data, data-monitoring

I got a new phone and I need to tell it that I've already used 25 megabytes this period. With the stock app I can I can set a usage limit, but I can't tell it how much I've already used this month.

Comment: Afraid that's not possible (except with some "root tricks", maybe). As a work-around you could set the limit lower by those 25M and re-adjust it to the real one next month.

Comment: @Izzy Indeed that is probably what all users getting a replacement phone in the middle of the month must do. Thankfully the pain only is for the first month, and I suppose we all will be using our new phone for many more months...

Comment: …with hopefully very few factory-resets :) I'm still having my 2013 device as "master". Thanks to custom ROMs I wasn't nailed to the "latest official" (Android 4.1.2) but can go at least up to MM (Android 6) with it. A clean flash (for a stable device) requires a factory reset, so this data stuff would be a task for "once per major upgrade". Thankfully I stay far below my allotted data plan, so I simply ignore those "wrong data" in the first month :)

Comment: OK submitted https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68463955

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Data usage, and you'll see a graph showing your data usage over a certain period. The coloured bars can be adjusted to set a warning, and also a limit, to stop you using too much data. Further down the page, you'll also see a list of your apps, and how much data they use.

You can also download alternative data monitoring apps https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping to do it with the stock app. It is apparently more impossible than adjusting the odometer on one's automobile.